# Where to add custom rewrite rules in .htaccess for URL rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an `.htaccess` with the following rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to add new rules that would let me rewrite URLs that contain uppercase letters into all lowercase. I need to add the following rule to my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This way a PHP script `rewrite-strtolower.php` would rewrite URLs containing uppercase letters. I'm using the script since I do not have access to the server config file.

This method was suggested in a blog post by Simon Holywell [link](https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2012/11/force-lowercase-urls-rewrite-php/)

The problem is that I cannot get it to work. I've tried adding it after the initial rules, before them as well as inside `<IfModule>` tags. That would not work in any of those configurations.

How should I add these new rules so that they are read and executed?

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is a resonable solution, but unfortunately, `rewrite-strtolower.php` is never executed. This is a URI that I entered `/section/bEAuty/`. It has not been modified.